# How to calculate a certain character in the Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to calculate the character 'a' in spark-shell.
I have a somewhat troublesome method, split by 'a' and "length - 1" is what i want.
Here is the code:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val test_data = sqlContext.read.json("music.json")
test_data.registerTempTable("test_data")
val temp1 = sqlContext.sql("select user.id_str as userid, text from test_data")
val temp2 = temp1.map(t => (t.getAs[String]("userid"),t.getAs[String]("text").split('a').length-1))
```

However, someone told me this is not remotely safe. I don't know why and can you give me a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not safe because if value is `NULL`:

```
val df = Seq((1, None), (2, Some("abcda"))).toDF("id", "text")
```

`getAs[String]` will return `null`:

```
scala> df.first.getAs[String]("text") == null
res1: Boolean = true
```

and `split` will give NPE:

```
scala> df.first.getAs[String]("text").split("a")
java.lang.NullPointerException
...
```

which is most likely the situation you got in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37299233/1560062).

One simple solution:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val aCnt = coalesce(length(regexp_replace($"text", "[^a]", "")), lit(0))
df.withColumn("a_cnt", aCnt).show

// +---+-----+-----+
// | id| text|a_cnt|
// +---+-----+-----+
// |  1| null|    0|
// |  2|abcda|    2|
// +---+-----+-----+
```

If you want to make your code relatively safe you should either check for existence of `null`:

```
def countAs1(s: String) = s match {
  case null => 0
  case chars => s.count(_ == 'a')
}

countAs1(df.where($"id" === 1).first.getAs[String]("text"))
// Int = 0

countAs1(df.where($"id" === 2).first.getAs[String]("text"))
// Int = 2
```

or catch possible exceptions:

```
import scala.util.Try

def countAs2(s: String) = Try(s.count(_ == 'a')).toOption.getOrElse(0)

countAs2(df.where($"id" === 1).first.getAs[String]("text"))
// Int = 0

countAs2(df.where($"id" === 2).first.getAs[String]("text"))
// Int = 2
```